# How to update JS object property inside jQuery Ajax callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, callback

I have a question as to how to update object property values inside Ajax call back function.
Here is the code:

```
var goldStar = {
        path: google.maps.SymbolPath.FORWARD_CLOSED_ARROW,
        fillColor: '',
        fillOpacity: 0.8,
        scale: 5,
        strokeOpacity: 0,
        strokeColor: '',
        rotation: '',
      };


if( some clause) {
 $.get("./ajaxEx.php", { nimo: nimo }, function(vesData) { 
   $(vesData).find("sTarget").each(function() {

      if (){ //some clause         

       goldStar.fillColor = 'red';
       goldStar.strokeColor = 'red';
      }

}

}
} else {

       goldStar.fillColor = 'green';
       goldStar.strokeColor = 'green';

}

console.log(goldStar)
```

console.log outputs like this:

```
Object {path: 1, fillColor: "green", fillOpacity: 0.8, scale: 5,     strokeOpacity: 0…}
fillColor: "red"
fillOpacity: 0.8
path: 1
rotation: 0
scale: 5
strokeColor: "red"
strokeOpacity: 0
__proto__: Object
```

My question is why Object appended with

fillColor: "red"
fillOpacity: 0.8
path: 1
rotation: 0
scale: 5
strokeColor: "red"
strokeOpacity: 0

Thanks.

Comment: You're already updating it, you just didn't wait long enough to see the change. Welcome to asynchronous logic

Comment: Thanks , what would be the correct way to update it?

Comment: ... the way you're doing it already is the only way to update it. The only thing "wrong" is you trying to console.log the value **before** the update has occurred.

Comment: but I update it inside if() clause. why I see goldStar.fillColor and goldStar.strokeColor set to green properly while 'red' just append to exisiting object

Comment: because... you're checking the value before the ajax call has completed. Think about it. What you're doing is similar to asking me to go to the store and pick up bread, and then stopping me at the door before I've left and asking me how much I spent at the store.

Comment: ok, how can I wait until ajax is done?  if I use 'complete: function(){}' I have same results

Comment: move the console.log into the success callback.

Comment: Ok, but how can I access updated object property outside the callback?

Comment: you can't, that isn't possible. Outside the callback happens before the callback does.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103766/discussion-between-kevin-b-and-user2257338).